# Add product status in tile view

Tags: category, product-attribute

I want to add product status to show in Tile View.(inside category) I can see that in grid view but not in Tile view. Anyone can advise me where I should modify?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its markup are located here which you can modify here:

```
vendor/magento/module-visual-merchandiser/view/adminhtml/templates/category/merchandiser/tile.phtml
```

or modify **getAttributesToDisplay** function found on:

```
vendor/magento/module-visual-merchandiser/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Merchandiser/Tile.php
```

or add your required product attribute on the **visualmerchandiser/options/product_attributes** Admin XML Configuration but it seems field doesn't not exist on the system.xml

```
vendor/magento/module-visual-merchandiser/etc/config.xml
vendor/magento/module-visual-merchandiser/etc/adminhtml/system.xml
```

P.S. Please make sure to override the core file if you want to make a modification on it.